# Groovy @ symbol before fields

Tags: reflection, groovy, private-members

What does @ means before a field name in Groovy? For some classes I am able to access private fields that are not directly accessible, let's take [ComposedClosure](http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=groovy-git.git;a=blob;f=src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ComposedClosure.java;h=37c1aba16b698565b38e807a32fd81f1dd85d21e;hb=42225e8ae6c679d3fb6c413d74225c859522015c) for example:

```
public class Person {
  private String name
}

def u = new Person(name:"Ron")
println u.@name //Ron
println u.name //Ron

a = {2} >> {3}
println a.@first //first closure object
println a.first //runtime error
```

Comment: Your ability to access private fields is a bug in the current Groovy implementation not a feature. You shouldn't use it because they will hopefully fix the bug in version 2.0 and it's bad OO practice

Comment: @Don It's not in the schedule for 2.0, it might be in 3.0, but I wouldn't hold my breath as the jury is still out as to whether it is a bug or a feature ;-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It allows you to override groovy's use of property accessors.  If you write:

```
println u.name
```

groovy will invoke the automatically generated getter Person.getName().  If you write:

```
println u.@name
```

it will go directly to the field like it would in Java.  In the case of the closure, it seems to have a `first` field but not a corresponding `getFirst` accessor.

In the groovy manual, it's documented as the [direct field access operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_direct_field_access_operator).

Answer (score 6):

It means you're accessing a field directly, rather than going through a getter.

See the [Groovy operator docs](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_direct_field_access_operator), although there isn't much more to say. Other than probably avoid it.

The reason it fails for a `ComposedClosure` is because there's no getter for `first` (or `second`).